# Azure function to create a database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Every month I get a copy of a database that I want to load into a new database. How would I go about creating a new database from within a Function? Would I need to use SQLCommands or utilising some Azure feature?

Thanks

Comment: This would probably help you [Automating a SQL Azure Database Copy](http://geekswithblogs.net/ScottKlein/archive/2010/09/09/automating-a-sql-azure-database-copy.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I would probably go with Azure Powershell to achieve that. I don't know what you are getting exactly, as you didn't specify, but Azure Powershell got some options to help you with that.

```
$importRequest = New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImport -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroup" `
   -ServerName $servername `
   -DatabaseName "MyImportSample" `
   -DatabaseMaxSizeBytes "262144000" `
   -StorageKeyType "StorageAccessKey" `
   -StorageKey $(Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroup" -StorageAccountName $storageaccountname).Value[0] `
   -StorageUri "http://$storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/importsample/sample.bacpac" `
   -Edition "Standard" `
   -ServiceObjectiveName "P6" `
   -AdministratorLogin "ServerAdmin" `
   -AdministratorLoginPassword $(ConvertTo-SecureString -String "ASecureP@assw0rd" -AsPlainText -Force)
```

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-import